# Serialized Data using jQuery does not Post to Action method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which I like to be submitted with `jQuery` `Ajax`. My `Ajax` function is something like following code :

```
   $('#submitForm').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Letter/Create',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                letterViewModel: $('#letterForm').serialize(),
                relatedLetters: JSON.stringify(relatedLetterList)
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success ' + result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

And my Action is :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(LetterViewModel letterViewModel, string relatedLetters)
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Here is the problem, first parameter of `Action` method is always `null`. I don't know what is the problem, any advice will be helpful.

**Update:** Data after serialization:

> __RequestVerificationToken=goQJDz5BCMx9NCJAZ3yuMA2E-WRgL9pJvavkLhF27epxkz3bRO_t-ADNhGHslHjXifLuxmFQcJBuOkMBSqMlFjkfKjVK-hGgY-nvRmp_2i81&CategoryId=1&LetterTitle=456&Exporter=465&ArchivePlace=456&OrgLetterNumber=456&OrgLetterDate_fa=1392%2F02%2F02&IndicatorNumber=456456&IndicatorDate_fa=1392%2F02%2F09&RelatedLetterId=3

And My `LetterViewModel`:

```
public class LetterViewModel
{
    public Int32 LetterId { get; set; }

    public Int32 RelatedLetterId { get; set; }

    public Int32 ServiceUserId { get; set; }

    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    public String LetterTitle { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrgLetterDate { get; set; }

    public String OrgLetterNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime IndicatorDate { get; set; }

    public String IndicatorNumber { get; set; }

    public String ArchivePlace { get; set; }

    public Boolean HasAppendix { get; set; }

    public Int32 PageCount { get; set; }

    public String Exporter { get; set; }

    public String OrgLetterDate_fa { get; set; }

    public String IndicatorDate_fa { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryViewModel> CategoryViewModels { get; set; }

    public List<VwLetterViewModel> RelatedLetters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what does `alert($('#letterForm').serialize())` give you?

Comment: I checked that, It serialize form but in the action method it is null.

Comment: Please additionally show the class declaration of `LetterViewModel`. A model that is `null` in the action usually means a mismatch between the class declaration and the received data.

Comment: serializing the data with jQuery creates a querystring, that querystring is normally interpreted by the server and parsed into an array or something similar, but as you're sending an object where one of the properties is a key with a serialized string, that does'nt happen, instead jQuery serializes the object containing the already serializes string.

Comment: Did you try replacing `.serialize()` with `.serializeArray()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
data: {
    letterViewModel: $('#letterForm').serialize(),
    relatedLetters: JSON.stringify(relatedLetterList)
},
```

The `.serialize()` method already performs an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` serialization of the data and jQuery data does another one so you end up with invalid request.

You could include a hidden field in your `#letterForm` and set its value immediately before posting the form:

```
$('#letterForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // set the value of the hidden field to the corresponding JSON
    $('#relatedLetters').val(JSON.stringify(relatedLetterList));

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success ' + result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Also notice that I have used the .submit event of the form instead of the .click event of a submit button. The reason for this is that a form can be submitted in other ways, not only by clicking on the submit button with a mouse. Think for example the user pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while inside some iof the form fields. This will submit the form and if you subscribe to the click event of your submit button your AJAX request will never fire.

Comment: Could'nt you also add it to the string : `$('#letterForm').serialize() + '&relatedLetters=' + JSON.stringify(relatedLetterList)`

Comment: Yes, this can also work, just make sure that you `encodeURIComponent` the value if you use this string concatenation to ensure proper encoding.

Comment: Did you ensure that the `name` of your hidden field is `relatedLetters`? Also make sure by inspecting the AJAX request with FireBug that the corresponding JSON value is being sent in this parameter.

Comment: There is no sign of serialized relatedLetters in POST, just my first parameter data.

Comment: Then your form probably doesn't contain a hidden field with that name. Make sure that it contains an `<input type="hidden" name="relatedLetters" value="" />`.

Comment: I tested so many times but `relatedLetters` value is now an empty string.

Comment: So the `$('#relatedLetters').val(JSON.stringify(relatedLetterList));` line doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I created another property RelatedLetterList in my ViewModel and remove second Action method parameters, and now it is working with some dirty.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before with Controllers and POST data as it differs from GET when sending variables, you need to send your data in JSON format, such as:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        letterViewModel: $('#letterForm').serialize(),
        relatedLetters: relatedLetterList // don't need to stringify this as it's done in JSON.stringify below
    }

    var obj = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Letter/Create',
        type: 'post',
        data: obj,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success ' + result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no $.toJSON method, and this does'nt make much sense to me ?

Comment: It's the one I  use, but in a separate library, changed to JSON.stringify. And it's what works for me, I've had the same issue numerous times.

Comment: @ChrisDixon thanks for your reply, I've tried, but this time second parameter relatedLetter is null.

Comment: So the first parameter is okay now? Try stringify on the relatedLetterList too then, see if this makes a difference (I don't know how your JS data model is).

Comment: Mind the fact relatedLetterList is a string in your Controller, make sure this is the appropriate type for what you're sending in...

Comment: What is the appropriate format for using instead of string type? Also I post my JS data in post, please take a look.

Comment: Well, the related letters are probably a List of the RelatedLetter type, just like your serialization of your View?